# Request to API using python request module <401> access denied response

Tags: python, python-requests

Im trying to make a simple `get` request to a public `API`. Looking through the docs http://api.vicroads.vic.gov.au/#overview from the `API` provider it mentions passing the auth token through as `header` formatted as `bearer`.. I think I have done correctly however I keep getting `<Response [401]> Access denied due to missing subscription key..` I also tried the other method mentioned by using `AUTH =`  but I get the same response `<Response [401]>....` Any help appreciated

```
<<HTTP Header method>>

import json 
import requests

auth_token='12345678910'
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}
url = 'https://data-exchange-api.vicroads.vic.gov.au/emergency_road_closures/allclosures'
response = requests.get(url, headers= header)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem with the token. The code looks fine

Comment: "{'Authorization': 'Bearer 12345678910'}" is this your aimed output?

Comment: I will request another token, I thought i may have formatted 'header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}' incorrectly. But looking at other SO qs it looked ok.

Comment: make sure the API endpoint is matching to the documentation, docs mention `http://api.vicroads.vic.gov.au` not `https://data-exchange-api.vicroads.vic.gov.au`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your `auth_token` is valid, try to use the alternative authentication method specified:

```
response = requests.get(url, params={'AUTH': auth_token})
```